# jquery .on() pass data through function

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I am reading the .on() jquery documentation.

And is it possible to pass some data like this:

```
function greet( event ) {
 alert( "Hello " + event.data.name );
}
$( "button" ).on( "click", {name: "Karl"}, greet );
```

The prototype of the methos is:

```
$(selector).on(event,childSelector,data,function,map)
```

Is it possible to have a more complex thin instead of only a string into the data parameter?.

In my case:
I will be generating dynamically some popups with a number input inside and some text.

Is it possible to capture the information inside the caller popup, i.e. the number and the text of the caller popup.
Maybe something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#id', 
var data =[
var number = functionThatGetTheNumberOfThePopup
var test = captureTextOfPopup
] , 
function(event){
//use number
//use test
});
```

Comment: yeah sure, basically whatever you want. Have you tried it yet? what went wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can pass any data, so an object would be fine, but the data is static, meaning that once it's passed to the event handler, changing it outside the event handler won't affect it. You should explain exactly how you're calling the event handler, why, and what you intend to do with this data, and you'll be more likely to get a working answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass arbitrary data. You do it in the form of an object:

```
$(document).on('click', '#id', {
        number: functionThatGetTheNumberOfThePopup,
        test: captureTextOfPopup
    },
    function(event){
    //use number
    console.log(event.data.number);
    //use test
    console.log(event.data.test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're example *does* pass something more complex than a "simple string" - you're example passes an object with one property `name` - there's no reason this couldnt be an object with 2 (or more) properties:

```
$(document).on('click', '#id', 
{
    number : functionThatGetTheNumberOfThePopup(),
    test : captureTextOfPopup()
} , 
function(event){
//use number
//use test
});
```