# unable to use jquery .on() to pass data through function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270791/jquery-on-pass-data-through-function) link to pass data to dynamically created element's click event. However, it does not work.

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var meterDiv = $("<div></div");
    meterDiv.attr('class', "container-fluid");
    var meterData = data[i].stompNumber + "<br/>" + data[i].stompName + "<br/>" + data[i].postId; 
    meterDiv.html(meterData);
    var postId=data[i].postID;
    meterDiv.on("click",  {postid: postId}, function(event) {
        parkedMeter(event);
        console.log("paked at : " + event.data.postid);
    })

    $("#meterInfo").append(meterDiv); 
}
```

`paked at` is `undefined` on console. Same as my `parkedMeter`:

```
function parkedMeter(event) {
  console.log("postid " + event.data.postid);
}
```

Comment: Please make [mcve], as it is your code snippet cannot be run, we don't know what the data-variable consist of nor how and where is parkedMeter-function declared.

Comment: The `.on()` method appears to be properly used: the question is, what is `postId`: and are you sure it is being read correctly? It seems like you have a typo: it should be `var postId = data[i].postId` instead of `var postId = data[i].postID`. Have you tried console logging what `data[i]` consists of? Then you will get a list of valid keys that you can use.

Comment: Terry's comment is correct.  I had typo error. Thanks Terry!!

Answer (score 0):

As per [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

on function parameter 1) event 2) selector 3) data object 4) callbackfunction/handler.

As your given code the selector is missing , You should add any selector

```
 meterDiv.on("click","Selector Here" , {postid: postId}, function(event) {
    parkedMeter(event);
    console.log("paked at : " + event.data.postid);
})
```

Comment: The selector is not required and can be omitted, as per the jQuery documentation.